# After login to Google Drive I want to show the files in it, but I get an error

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I am getting the error:

> The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file

when trying to show files from Google Drive.

```swift
func handleSignInButton() {
    //        let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: "356464518615-9meu8jn6nn2a0gu2415ar8cn01ml8b4u.apps.googleusercontent.com")
    guard let presentingViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first
                                          as? UIWindowScene)?.windows.first?.rootViewController else {return}
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(withPresenting: presentingViewController)  { user, error in
        guard let result = user else {
            // Inspect error
            return
        }

        let driveScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"
        let fileScope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
        let grantedScopes = GIDGoogleUser().grantedScopes
        if grantedScopes == nil || !grantedScopes!.contains(driveScope) || !grantedScopes!.contains(fileScope){
            // Request additional Drive scope.
            let additionalScopes = [driveScope, fileScope]
            guard let currentUser = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.currentUser else {
                return ;  /* Not signed in. */
            }
            
            currentUser.addScopes(additionalScopes, presenting: presentingViewController) { signInResult, error in
                guard error == nil else { return }
                guard signInResult != nil else { return }
                // Check if the user granted access to the scopes you requested.
            }
                            
            openAllFilesOnGoogleDrive()
        }
    }
}

func openAllFilesOnGoogleDrive() {
    let service = GTLRDriveService()
    service.apiKey = "AIzaSyBYCmoxlaXj_HI8bTj1jlQTmJ2GI64ZP2Q"
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesList.query()
    query.spaces = "drive"
    query.corpora = "user"
    query.fields = "files(id,name,modifiedTime,size)"
    let audioOrVideoFiles = "mimeType contains 'audio/' or mimeType contains 'video/'"
    query.q = "\(audioOrVideoFiles)"
    
    service.executeQuery(query) { _, result, error in
        if let error = error {
            // Handle error
            print("Error retrieving file list: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        if let fileList = result as? GTLRDrive_FileList {
            for file in fileList.files ?? [] {
                fileListArray.append(file)
                print("fileListArray \(fileListArray)")
                print("File name: \(file.name ?? "")")
                print("File ID: \(file.identifier ?? "")")
                print("File Size: \(file.size ?? 0)")
                print("--------------------")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have given full access and transferred permission from private to everyone